# RStudio project file in blank when open

Tags: r, rstudio

I've worked on some projects in RStudio normally until this. Suddenly when I tried to open those RStudio project files (.Rproj), the files, environment and script panes appear in  blank and the console don't respond like the image. The problem follows even when I created a new empty project in the same folder the old bad project. It's weird because instead I can create a new empty project in my desktop (in this path works perfect) and I can open the scripts and files of the old  projects, so the files are good, but I think the problem is in the .Rproj file.

I tryed to reinstall RStudio, rename the directory C:\Users\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop to reset the configurations but it doesn't work.

I've  Windows 10, RStudio (Version 1.0.153) and R version 3.4.1. Hope you can help me.

Thanks for your help.

[This Image shows the blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc7nS.png)

Comment: You might also try deleting the (hidden) `.Rproj.user` directory within that project. Also, if you haven't already, you might try installing the [preview release](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time Kevin.
I've tried those things but persist the problem. I think is because the project is in my Google Drive directory or something like that...

Comment: That's certainly possible -- RStudio projects hosted in auto-syncing folders (e.g. Dropbox, Google Drive) often don't behave well. What if you try (temporarily) copying to a separate directory, just for testing?